# When Summoning Custom Villager, Can you trade enchanted gear?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Here is my command: `/summon Villager ~1 ~ ~ {Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:"diamond",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"diamond_boots",Count:1,ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000}]},rewardExp:false}]}}` and it doesn't work. How can I integrate enchanted gear into a villager's trading palette?

Comment: Does it give you any error, or does it just not give you what you want?

Comment: Gives normal boots, not enchanted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The item format dictates that all data except for the root `id`, `Damage`, `Count`, and `Slot` tags must be placed within a single `tag` compound, which includes enchantments:

```
/summon Villager ~1 ~ ~ {Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:"diamond",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"diamond_boots",Count:1,tag:{ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000}]}},rewardExp:false}]}}
```